# JQuery RSS pugin - object doesnt support this property or method for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a SharePoint environment where I used RSS feed for pulling news. The RSS feed is coming from a url. Now when the page loads, RSS feed duplicates the same feed data from the news and shows it twice, instead of restricting it to 3 items, This works for Chrome, it does not work in IE8,
eg:

```
news title (eg New york times)
a
b
c
```

but when it renders the page it gives me

```
news title
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

Now there is a drop down menu to select what news feed you want and that works well (I mean it does not duplicate and shows only 3 items), it only fails when you load the whole site

I get the IE error object doesn't support this property or method,

```
this.selectednews.subscribe(function (val) {

        require(['../vendor/jquery/jquery.rss.min', 'jquery'], function (rss, $) {

            var url = self.selectednews().LinkURL();

            $("#rssfeed").empty();

    // ----------- Breaks from this line in IE   .........................     
             $("#rssfeed").rss(url, {
                limit: 3,
                effect: 'slideFast',
                entryTemplate: '<li class="cf"><span class="title"><a href="{url}">{title}</a></span></li>',
                layoutTemplate: "<ul class='events'>{entries}</ul>"

            });

            self.rssupdate();

        });
    });
```

would really appreciate some help for this guys, thanks

Comment: I understand this has been posted a while back by myself, but it would not look good for others having the same problem if i dont answer them , What i found out is using the function empty() in   $("#rssfeed").empty() does not really work in IE 8 and does not clear the entries after page load,  try using html('') this should work in IE8 , now i coudnt test this as we upgraded to IE 11 later, but would be nice if somebody could confirm. hope it helps guys